# Python "do...until" iteration until a condition is met with function updating

Tags: python, function, iteration, do-while, auto-update

I have a general question about the "do...until" iteration until a condition is met.

Let's say that I have a variable `x`, `y` and `z`, where:

`x0 = function(y0)`
I ran the code, and from the function, I got a value `x0` from an inputted variable value `y0`.
With the value of `x0`, now I have to update `y0` and get a new value of `y1=function(x0)`.
The process is repeated in the next step, and now I should get:
`x1 = function(y1)`
and again, from `x1`, to update `y1` and get a new value of `y2=function(x1)`.

The iteration should stop when the condition of `x(i-1) - x(i) =~ 0` is met,
and after that, it should continue with a new calculation, which will have:

`z = function(y(i))`

I'm new to these "do...until" iterations, and my main problem is setting up the condition.

Here is a picture of the results of the example that I solved by running the code a few times manually iterating:

[image: Manual Iteration]

I didn't post the code for the functions because they are long. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: *"I didn't post the code..."* It's really helpful to see your code. Maybe you can boil it down to a simple example so it isn't so long?

Comment: [This](https://realpython.com/python-while-loop/) explain the usage of `while True` and break condition. Can be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works just like the "do ... until" you described:

```py
while not [condition]:
    ...
```

so you can write either something like this:

```py
y = y0
x = function(y)
last_x = -1

while not (-.0001 <= last_x - x <= .0001):
    y = function(x)
    last_x = x
    x = function(y)
    print(x, y, last_x)
```

or (if you want to keep track of all your x's and y's):

```py
y = [y0]
x = []

while len(x) <= 1 or not (-.0001 <= x[-2] - x[-1] <= .0001):
    x.append(function(y[-1]))
    y.append(function(x[-1]))
```